# Verifying an XML attribute using Jayway's rest-assured

Tags: java, xml, api, soap, rest-assured

I am trying to verify that **xmlns:ns1="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"** in the following XML using Jayway's rest-assured's [XML support](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/blob/master/xml-path/src/test/java/com/jayway/restassured/path/xml/XmlPathTest.java).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getBankResponse xmlns:ns1="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">
      <ns1:details>
        <ns1:bezeichnung>ABK-Kreditbank</ns1:bezeichnung>
        <ns1:bic>ABKBDEB1XXX</ns1:bic>
        <ns1:ort>Berlin</ns1:ort>
        <ns1:plz>10789</ns1:plz>
      </ns1:details>
    </ns1:getBankResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As I understand it,

```
xmlns:ns1="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"
```

is an *attribute* of

```
<ns1:getBankResponse
```

The **@** prefix should return an attribute matching the stem following the **@**.

Assume that **xmlString** is equal to the above SOAP response XML, all of the following have returned null:

```
String nameSpace1 = given(xmlString).getString("Envelope.Body.getBankResponse.@xmlns:ns1");
String nameSpace2 = given(xmlString).getString("Envelope.Body.getBankResponse.@ns1");
String nameSpace3 = given(xmlString).getString("Envelope.Body.getBankResponse.@xmlns");
List<String> nameSpace = given(xmlString).get("Envelope.Body.getBankResponse[0].@xmlns:ns1");
List<String> nameSpace = given(xmlString).get("Envelope.Body.getBankResponse[0].@ns1");
List<String> nameSpace = given(xmlString).get("Envelope.Body.getBankResponse[0].@xmlns");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I know that rest-assured is primarily concerned with RESTful APIs but it can be used to test SOAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the upcoming version of REST Assured (probably 2.9.1) you will be able to configure XmlPath to be unaware of namespaces. So this means you can do like this:

```
XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(xmlResponse).using(xmlPathConfig().namespaceAware(false));
assertThat(xmlPath.getString("soapenv:Envelope.soapenv:Body.ns1:getBankResponse.@xmlns:ns1"), equalTo("http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"));
```

You can try this out today by depending on version `2.9.1-SNAPSHOT` after having added the following Maven repository:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots />
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved it this way:

```
 XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(xmlResponse).using(xmlPathConfig().declaredNamespace("ns1", "http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"));

// Then

 assertThat(xmlPath.getString("Envelope.Body.getBankResponse.ns1:details.ns1:bezeichnung.text()"), equalTo("ABK-Kreditbank"));
```

I say partially because while it does prove that name space *ns1* is used and therefore must be defined to be valid it doesn't show that:

```
xmlns:ns1="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/"
```

because the test still passes if I change the URI.

Anybody have a better answer?

Comment: There's no better option in the currently released version (2.9.0).